# One Oracle connection through out the session in MVC

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, oracle11g, session-variables, session-state

I need to create a single connection for the entire session of a user in MVC.

Below code wrote in the Login controller for achieving the same

```
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();
con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleConnection"].ConnectionString;
con.Open();
Session["oracle_con"] = con;
```

then whenever I need the connection will check as below

```
 OracleConnection or_con = (OracleConnection)Session["oracle_con"];
  if (or_con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    or_con.Open();
```

This is working fine in my local system, sessin sate mode is **'InProc'**

But in server the session state mode is **"StateServer"** , so the conversion of Oracle connection to session is giving the below error

> Unable to serialize the session state. In 'StateServer' and
>   'SQLServer' mode, ASP.NET will serialize the session state objects,
>   and as a result non-serializable objects or MarshalByRef objects are
>   not permitted. The same restriction applies if similar serialization
>   is done by the custom session state store in 'Custom' mode.
>
> [SerializationException: Type
>   'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection' in Assembly
>   'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' is not marked as serializable.]

Is this the right way or any other way to achieve my requirement?

Comment: Generally, storing a connection in session is an old, and bad practice. It impedes the ability to properly use connection pooling. Connections are one of the most valuable resource you can have, and keeping one around without it being returned to the pool will cause the server to eventually run out. Generally, connections should be created, opened, used immediately and closed as soon as data is retrieved in order to return them to the pool.

Comment: @MarkFitzpatrick i agree with u..pblm here is each time when i try to open the connection its taking more than 1 min and its making the application slow..its issue from oracle database..and they are not able to fix yet

Answer (score 0):

OracleConnection doesn’t implement Serializable so that won’t work for what you’re trying to do. Why do you want to put the connection in a session? ODP.NET uses a connection pool by default so a new connection request doesn’t have to be created from scratch.

If the connection is slow to create, it can be because of missing log folders that has to be created, C:\oracle_client\log\diag\clients.

See here, [Creating 32-bit ODP.Net OracleConnection object is very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15009090/creating-32-bit-odp-net-oracleconnection-object-is-very-slow?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), and here, http://milagaia.blogspot.com/2012/04/odpnet-slow-first-connection.html?m=1.

Comment: i agree with u..pblm here is each time when i try to open the connection its taking more than 1 min and its making the application slow..its issue from oracle..and they are not able to fix yet

Comment: It could be because of a missing folder it’s looking for.

Comment: missing folder in oracle?

Comment: Not on the Oracle server but where the application is running.

Comment: its happening in all application..If i write a simple form app also its the same